# install GEOS library on linux without sudo permission

Tags: python, linux, geos

I use python on department computer, for which I don't have `sudo` permission.

I try to do `import shapely.geometry` but I get error when I'm importing it:

```
OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']
```

Then I tried to install the `geos` library. I did so by following steps:

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
tar xjf geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2

cd nas/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2
./configure --prefix=/nax/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2  --enable-python && make clean && make
make install
```

However, right after it I got some errors:

```
test -z "/nas/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2/include/geos/algorithm/locate" || /usr/bin/mkdir -p "/nas/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2/include/geos/algorithm/locate"/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/nas/local’: Permission denied
make[7]: *** [install-geosHEADERS] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory `/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2/include/geos/algorithm/locate'
make[6]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[6]: Leaving directory `/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2/include/geos/algorithm/locate'
make[5]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2/include/geos/algorithm/locate'
make[4]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2/include/geos/algorithm'
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2/include/geos'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2/include'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/yangj/geos-3.4.2'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Any idea to solve this problem?
Besides, I have a feeling that I should set path variable when I install this library, but I am very unfamiliar with path setting. If path setting is required in your answer, could you please explain it clearly?

Comment: `/nas/local` vs `/nax/local/` ?

Comment: anyway you should choose a directory in which you have write permission.

Comment: BTW, those `/nas/` and `/nax/` look pretty weird for me.